# Why the loop .each in ruby just runs a half?

Tags: ruby, loops

I got a problem while using this loop:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a.each{puts "#{a.shift}"}
```

a I just got 1, 2. Any one can help me?

Comment: `each` and `shift` doesn't play well together like @mudasobwa already pointed out. What you you try to achieve? Just print all elements in the array? That would be just: `a.each { |n| puts n }`

Comment: It's the same problem like with this question: [Delete element of array while iterating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35499378/delete-element-of-array-while-iterating/35499700#35499700). I wrote a long explanation for.

Answer (score 5):

`Array#shift` removes the first value from an array and returns it. So when you're looping through the array, the array is modified.

The `each` method seems to basically loop until the index is greater than or equal to the length of the array. Because you're removing elements from the array as you loop the array's length decreases. When you have removed two elements the index is at 2 and the length is 2, so the `.each` loop exits.

i.e.:

```
Index: 0
Array: [1, 2, 3, 4]
Print: 1

Index: 1
Array: [2, 3, 4]
Print: 2

Index: 2 # Exit here
Array: [3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Array#shift`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-shift) modifies an array inplace. One might either iterate and print values, or use a loop unless the mutated array is empty:

```
a.each { |elem| puts elem }
#⇒ a is still [1,2,3,4]
```

or

```
while a.size > 0 do puts a.shift end
#⇒ a is empty []
```

or

```
until a.empty? do puts a.shift end
#⇒ a is empty []
```

In your example `a` is mutated, hence on third iteration there is no more elements to iterate.