# Python : Using list.pop( ) in for loops, + please explain the process how it happens )edited

Tags: python, list, for-loop

## Explain

---

i want **get all items** in for loops using list and method **pop**(default)

given the follow code:

```py
text = ['a','b','c']

for i in text:
    print(i)
```

it returns all items in list
`a b c`

## Ploblem

---

but when i tried this code

```py
text = ['a','b','c']

for i in text: 
   z=text.pop()
   print(z)
print('remains text :',text)
```

it returns :
`c b remains text : ['a']`

item 'a' still left in text[ ]

**why??** the **Explain** code prints all items but this does not

i think it has to be *loop for 3 times and get all items*

but **only 2 times working**

---

i want know why can't loop all counts

it has to happens 3 times but only 2 times

thx.

---

sorry for re-asking

so i get it 'text' is mutable so when loop execute 'text' it will be changed but

i dont get the mechanism why ['a'] remains

can you explain about the process?

pop():

['a','b','c'] > ['a','b'] > ['a']

i mean.... it changes but i think still does't matter to
print c b a

left 1 items but it works in for()

this is exatly what i want

```py
text = ['a']

for i in text: 
   z=text.pop()
   print(z)
print('remains text :',text)
```

result :
`a remains text : []`

**for more explain**

```
text = ['a','b','c']

for i in text: 
   print('text',text)
   z=text.pop()
   print('pop:',z)
   print('remains text :',text)
```

`

text ['a', 'b', 'c']

pop: c

remains text : ['a', 'b']

text ['a', 'b']

pop: b

remains text : ['a']

`

> left 1 but not working!!

sorry that i'm fool :)

Comment: You've got the same problem as I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35548700/why-the-loop-each-in-ruby-just-runs-a-half/35548883#35548883)

Comment: Don't modify the list you are iterating over.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice that's a rule I follow religiously no matter what language I'm working in.

Comment: sorry guys i was got it wrong about python grammer you guys very helpful to solve this problem it reminds me how much important about basis. you're the savior have a good day